# Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm just trying to do something very basic on my Mac using selenium and I can't even open a webpage. I'm getting an error of :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/godsinred/Desktop/InstagramLiker/GmailAccountGenerator.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Here is my code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

link = "https://accounts.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

The error clearly mentions that the *chromedriver* which is getting detected have wrong permissions.

---

### Solution

- Download the latest *chromedriver* binary from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and save it in your system.
- Ensure that *chromedriver* binary have the required permissions.
- While initiating the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* pass the argument **executable_path** along with the absolute path of the *chromedriver* binary as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  link = "https://accounts.google.com"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
  driver.get(link)
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- ['Webdrivers' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo/47150939#47150939)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked out. I also forgot to add it to my paths.
executed sudo paths /etc/paths/ in the terminal and added the chrome driver to the paths directory

Answer (score 21):

Most answers here and in other related posts suggest users to just move the file to `/usr/bin` and they work fine if you are just running `chromedriver` locally and normally.

However, if you are compiling Python scripts into executables using compilers such as `cx_freeze`, you may not be able to afford the luxury if your program always uses a relative link to `chromedriver`.

As the error message suggests, your compiled program does not have the permissions to manipulate `chromedriver`. To use a relative link to `chromedriver` on a Mac in your compiled Python program, you can programmatically change the permission of `chromedriver` in your Python script using:

```
import os
os.chmod('/path/to/chromedriver', 0755) # e.g. os.chmod('/Users/user/Documents/my_project/chromedriver', 0755)
```

---

You can test this by doing the following:

1. `cd` to your working directory
2. `$ chmod 755 chromedriver` to allow your program to manipulate it

> P.S. `755` is the default numerical permission for files in `usr/bin`. `664` is the default numerical permission for files in other normal folders (probably your working directory). Thus, when `chromedriver` complains it does not have the correct permission, you need to grant it a numerical permission equivalent to or greater than `755`.

Comment: python3 would need "0o755"

Comment: I found that this can also be used to allow chromedriver to run when placed in temp directories as well. Can be very useful when running tests

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows give path including file name. For example,
'./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
My line of code looks like below.

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 0):

This worked! I followed these instructions to update PATH: https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/

I dragged my chromedriver.exe from Finder into Terminal (/etc/paths), and then copied the address in Terminal and dropped it into my Python IDE where the PATH should be inserted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check out a this topics

1- If you are using Linux, access the folder containing the file
Chromedriver.exe set on 755

2- check correct path for  Chromedriver.exe file in your code

3- If you are using Windows servers,check the Chromedriver.exe file is available for the current user (**not only the admin** does have access to Chromedriver.exe - see in c://users...)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Windows was adding the location of the driver to Windows local `PATH` var, restarting my python environment so that the path to the driver displayed after running this:

```
import os;path = os.getenv('PATH'); print(path);
```

and then I did not specify the path when loading the driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
```

if I tried putting the path in the `Chrome()` call it caused the permissions error. Adding it to the local environment path is enough.