# Python Selenium webdriver chromedriver 'may have wrong permissions' (OSX 10.13)

Tags: python, macos, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/John/Desktop')

browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

To execute in terminal:

```
python seleniumtest.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/John/Desktop'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/John/Desktop')
  File "/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Desktop' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I have chromedriver installed as far as I'm aware, what's going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions)

Comment: Your 'Desktop' is not an executable path. Edit your path to show the executable google driver.

Comment: solved it. Needed to move chromedriver executable to the local/bin. Thanks guys it works now

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer an alternative solution which does not require you to move `chromedriver` to `local/bin`. This was originally posted as an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577896/5305519). Just sharing this in case anyone stumbles upon this question when using `cx_freeze` on Mac.

---

Most answers here and in other related posts suggest users to just move the file to `/usr/bin` and they work fine if you are just running `chromedriver` locally and normally.

However, if you are compiling Python scripts into executables using compilers such as `cx_freeze`, you may not be able to afford the luxury if your program always uses a relative link to `chromedriver`.

As the error message suggests, your compiled program does not have the permissions to manipulate `chromedriver`. To use a relative link to `chromedriver` on a Mac in your compiled Python program, you can programmatically change the permission of `chromedriver` in your Python script using:

```
import os
os.chmod('/path/to/chromedriver', 0755) # e.g. os.chmod('/Users/user/Documents/my_project/chromedriver', 0755)
```

---

You can test this by doing the following:

1. `cd` to your working directory
2. `$ chmod 755 chromedriver` to allow your program to manipulate it

> P.S. `755` is the default numerical permission for files in `usr/bin`. `664` is the default numerical permission for files in other normal folders (probably your working directory). Thus, when `chromedriver` complains it does not have the correct permission, you need to grant it a numerical permission equivalent to or greater than `755`.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna throw another solution into the pot.

I had it like this:

```
import requests, json, os, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
my_headers = {}
my_headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
```

did

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

and still got the error.

Then I downloaded the matching chromedriver binary at

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

and placed it in the root of my script. That seemed to do the trick!