# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions using Google Colaboratory through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Chrome version 83.0.4103.116 and ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39. I am trying to use chrome driver in google colab. I use the path of chromedriver after uploading it in google colab. Could you please point out where i m getting error.
This is the code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(r'/content/chromedriver.exe')
```

This is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

4 frames
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     86                 raise WebDriverException(
     87                     "'%s' executable may have wrong permissions. %s" % (
---> 88                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     89                 )
     90             else:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Google Colaboratory

[Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16pBJQePbqkz3QFV54L4NIkOn1kwpuRrj#scrollTo=DO6Z47v1bO-w) is a free Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup and runs entirely in the cloud which enables us to write and execute code, save and share your analyses, and access powerful computing resources, all for free from your browser.

The entire colab runs in a cloud VM. If you investigate the VM you will find that the current colab notebook is running on top of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

So while using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) instead of mentioning the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant along with the extension i.e. `.exe` you need to drop the extension. So effectively your code block will be:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome('/content/chromedriver')
```

---

### Update

Incase you aren't sure where the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) is getting downloaded you can move it to a known location and use it as follows:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed relevant discussions in:

- ['Webdrivers' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo/47150939#47150939)
- [Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions/49788993#49788993)

Comment: While trying to run without exe then it gives this error WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: '/content/chromedriver.exe' is the path i got after uploding chromedrive file in the google colab

Comment: @SoudipKarmakar That sounds to be a different issue completely. Can you raise a new question as per yournew requirement please?

Comment: wd = webdriver.Chrome(r'/content/chromedriver.exe' )that what I am talking. After uploading the chromedriver file in the google colab, '/content/chromedriver.exe'  is the path of the uploaded file.There is no error from the path. But while i m using this-wd=webdriver.Chrome('/content/chromedriver') then i get this error-While trying to run without exe then it gives this error WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: @SoudipKarmakar Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes it is working. But at the end this error comes :MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=43465): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/97f397fa9f8f046a5b44bf75808d09c6/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7458f550f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)). I am not able to sort out the solution from there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703937/http-connection-pool-error-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection?noredirect=1#comment110895056_62703937

Comment: @SoudipKarmakar Again, `MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool()` is a different error and you need to address it differently.

Comment: yes i m asking in different question. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703937/http-connection-pool-error-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection

Answer (score 0):

I made a library to help using selenium in Colab easier.

You can just call this

```py
!pip install kora -q
from kora.selenium import wd
wd.get(url)
```

Comment: After executing this from kora.selenium import wd i get this error.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Comment: Try start it in a new notebook. It might interfere with our previous chromedriver.

Comment: I m starting in new notebook. wd.get('https://google.com') after this line i get this error:MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=44451): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/d653bd20a28ef757c930aba4d7283777/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe0e93d1f60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Comment: I think it is okay. Due to some other function it might happen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703937/http-connection-pool-error-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection Could you please check once the problem. I am posting the whole code over there and the error what i have got.