# How do I give permission to chromedriver.exe?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

## I use chrome driver during face recognition project, but I get an error in the 4th line below.
How do I give permission to chromedriver.exe?

code:

```
data_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/faces' 
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path,f))]
url='https://www.naver.com/' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
```

======================================================================================================
error message:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

4 frames
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/FaceRecognition/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     86                 raise WebDriverException(
     87                     "'%s' executable may have wrong permissions. %s" % (
---> 88                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     89                 )
     90             else:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Do you really use chromedriver.EXE on a Unix System?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/'
.
WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** exexutable wasn't detected and hence [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) suspects that the executable may have wrong permissions.

---

### Solution

While passing the *Key* **`executable_path`** you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *WebDriver* variant name, i.e. **`chromedriver`** as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/content/chromedriver')
                          webdriver variant name ^^^chromedriver^^^ needs to be appended
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- ['Webdrivers' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo/47150939#47150939)
- [Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions/49788993#49788993)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you do not use chromedriver.EXE on Unix Systems, right?