# Chromedriver V93+ error message "Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

At first I thought it was something to do with the code I was trying to drive with selenium, but with a simplified test of go to google.com I ran into the following error.

*WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions.*

With chromedriver V93 and V94 I obtain the following error message when I try to run the executable file by itself:

*"Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the file"*

I do not obtain this error on any previous versions of chromedriver up to V92. I've tried to check permissions and that doesn't appear to be the root cause from what I can tell. It seems as though V93 and V94 throw this error and I can't seem to figure out why that would be.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions)

Comment: I don't think so, I am running on Windows not Mac. I've tried giving chromedriver path permissions as well as running as admin. If I use an earlier version V92 and lower I don't have any issues, it's only for V93 onwards for some reason.

Comment: Did you set perms through code?

Comment: As it's a windows file system chmod won't work. As far as I can tell it has the right permission. When I tried to change the permission through the command line with `chromedriver /P <user>:F` I get "Access is denied". The thing I can't understand is this is only occurring on the latest chromedriver versions.

Comment: Strangely, V95 which just same out for the version of chrome in development I don't have the problem. So V92 works, V93 and V94 do not, with V95 working again... very confusing.