# Selenium with Pydroid

Tags: python, selenium, pydroid

I have a basic webscraper using Selenium which I would like to be able to run on my phone when I am away from my PC. I need information generated by Javascript so Beautiful Soup isn't an option. I found Pydroid which allows me to run Python scripts on my android device but am having issues running Selenium. This is the basic code I'm trying to run

```
from selenium import webdriver    
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(),options=options)
```

I've also tried a suggestion I saw online

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

But this dives a Permission denied for the chromedriver folder.

Comment: How does the folder with the webdriver called? Does the folder name is the same as the file name (`chromedriver`)?

Comment: I think you need the phone hooked up to your computer to do this.  (or a Droid emulator) At one point there was a port of HTMLUnit to android though... never used it, and I don't think it's been updated in a while:  https://github.com/null-dev/HtmlUnit-Android  Your other option would be to use your phone to control your computer at home to run Selenium scripts.

Comment: @pcalkins, yeah I thought that was the case, just checking if someone would somehow know another way.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex yes, it only asks for File and Media permissions which I've granted and it says No permissions denied.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex 12. What device have you gotten it working on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case but you might get `Permission denied` exception in case `chromedriver` file is located in the folder with the same name and so when you passed `'./chromedriver'` to `webdriver.Chrome` call Python tries to execute folder as file.

So make sure you pass file but not folder

Comment: I tried that, I still get a `Permission denied`. This time it also says `'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home`. I don't see anything there that helps though.

Comment: @L10Yn did you check these answers: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions/53577896#53577896), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo/47255840#47255840)?

Comment: Yes I've tried adding the line `os.chmod('./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', 0o755)` but it still gives the same error

Comment: @L10Yn I believe there is a typo. It should be `os.chmod('./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', 0755)`

Comment: If I do that I get the error message `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted: use an 0o prefix for octal integers`, one of the comments in that post mentioned in Python3 it has to be how I have it there