# Is it possible to host a selenium app on a server?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, streamlit

### Description:

Hi there, I have created a Selenium app that's interactive and changeable according to users need with the help of Streamlit interface. The app itself is working perfectly fine without any issue, additionally all the packages that needs to be installed are added inside of the `requirements.txt` file. So no package issue at all.

### Issue:

The issue is when I upload the app on selenium or any other web-server such as GitHub Codespace the app doesn't run. The error is generated by this line:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

### Tried Solutions:

I have tried downloading the chrome driver and placing it inside the working directory and use `external_path = "./chromedriver.exe"` argument but no luck there. I am open to any suggestions, Thank you.

### Code Snippet:

```py
if st.button("Scrape Data"):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    driver.get(f'https://www.airbnb.com{"" if location == f"I{comma}m flexible" else f"/s/{location}"}/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&price_filter_input_type=0&channel=EXPLORE&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&price_filter_num_nights=6&checkin={check_in_date}&checkout={check_out_date}{f"&adults={adults_count}" if adults_count > 0 else ""}{f"&children={children_count}" if children_count > 0 else ""}{f"&infants={infants_count}" if infants_count > 0 else ""}{f"&pets={pets_count}" if pets_count > 0 else ""}&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D={"one_week" if additional_search_filters == False else stay}{f"&max_price={max_price}" if additional_search_filters else ""}{f"&min_price={min_price}" if additional_search_filters and min_price > 10 else ""}')
    
    titles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.t1jojoys.atm_g3_1kw7nm4.atm_ks_15vqwwr.atm_sq_1l2sidv.atm_9s_cj1kg8.atm_6w_1e54zos.atm_fy_1vgr820.atm_7l_18pqv07.atm_cs_qo5vgd.atm_w4_1eetg7c.atm_ks_zryt35__1rgatj2.dir.dir-ltr')
    subtitles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.t6mzqp7.atm_g3_1kw7nm4.atm_ks_15vqwwr.atm_sq_1l2sidv.atm_9s_cj1kg8.atm_6w_1e54zos.atm_fy_kb7nvz.atm_7l_12u4tyr.atm_am_qk3dho.atm_ks_zryt35__1rgatj2.dir.dir-ltr')
    prices = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span._tyxjp1')
    ratings = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.r1dxllyb.atm_7l_18pqv07.atm_cp_1ts48j8.dir.dir-ltr')
    links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.l1ovpqvx.atm_1y33qqm_1ggndnn_10saat9.atm_17zvjtw_zk357r_10saat9.atm_w3cb4q_il40rs_10saat9.atm_1cumors_fps5y7_10saat9.atm_52zhnh_1s82m0i_10saat9.atm_jiyzzr_1d07xhn_10saat9.bn2bl2p.atm_5j_8todto.atm_9s_1ulexfb.atm_e2_1osqo2v.atm_fq_idpfg4.atm_mk_stnw88.atm_tk_idpfg4.atm_vy_1osqo2v.atm_26_1j28jx2.atm_3f_glywfm.atm_kd_glywfm.atm_3f_glywfm_jo46a5.atm_l8_idpfg4_jo46a5.atm_gi_idpfg4_jo46a5.atm_3f_glywfm_1icshfk.atm_kd_glywfm_19774hq.atm_uc_x37zl0_1w3cfyq_oggzyc.atm_70_thabx4_1w3cfyq_oggzyc.atm_uc_glywfm_1w3cfyq_pynvjw.atm_uc_x37zl0_18zk5v0_oggzyc.atm_70_thabx4_18zk5v0_oggzyc.atm_uc_glywfm_18zk5v0_pynvjw.dir.dir-ltr')
    
    for title, subtitle, price, rating, link in zip(titles, subtitles, prices, ratings, links):
        if output == "Markdown":
            data["Title"].append(title.text)
            data["Subtitle"].append(subtitle.text)
            data["Price"].append(price.text)
            data["Rating"].append(f"⭐{rating.text}")
            data["Link"].append(link.get_attribute("href"))

            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/mount/src/airbnb-webscraper/main.py", line 83, in <module>

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__

    super().__init__(

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__

    self.service.start()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start

    self.assert_process_still_running()

  File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running

    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/appuser/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/122.0.6261.94/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Comment: You need both the Chrome driver and the Chrome browser itself.  Neither are guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm, so it's safe to say that it's not possible?

Comment: What error are you getting? It is certainly possible to run selenium headless on a server or in a CI pipeline.

Comment: Well the error is that when I am running on a server its not finding the chromedriver currently I followed the below answer but now I am getting the executable_path error, working on that currently.

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question, otherwise it is impossible for us to help you.

Comment: Sure, totally forgot to do that.

Comment: @Jeppe so I edited the question and added the error. BTW sorry for late reply!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you have installed a suitable version of the ChromeDriver. Then, try to configure your driver like that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set Chrome options for headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver with options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Any solution to this: `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'`, the executable_path is not an accepted argument how come its that?

Comment: Upon further research I bumped upon the solution that selenium 4.10.0 doesnt support the `executable_path` argument so should I reduce the version to 4.9.1 or so?

Comment: @AshhadDevLab refer this documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#executable_path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-service-object

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions.`

Comment: the user that is running your selenium app must be eligible to run ChromeDriver.

Comment: So what is the solution here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787327/selenium-on-mac-message-chromedriver-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions

Comment: Well this is definitely not helpful for me, I already read this one before but no luck. I also mentioned that executable_path is not working in the newer versions