# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'WebScraping' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to make this work. It always displays the wrong permission. I have downloaded the chromedriver version 96 and my chrome version is 96. I know that the executable path has been depreciated and changed it to Service. Can anybody help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

chrome_driver_path = "/Users/thangtruong/WebScraping"
service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
website = "https://www.amazon.com"
driver.get(website)
```

Comment: you can check permissions on the file and change if necessary.  Is this java?  (And what is "WebScraping" executable? Did you rename the chromedriver?.. if not, it may be trying to execute a folder...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

- If your underlying [os](/questions/tagged/os) is [windows](/questions/tagged/windows):

  - You have to download **chromedriver_win32.zip** from the [ChromeDriver Download Location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.16/) and unzip it for usage.
  - Additionally, if you are explicitly specifying the *Chromedriver* binary path you have to append the binary extension as well, effectively i.e. *chromedriver.exe*.
  - While mentioning the *Chromedriver* binary path you have to either use the single [forward slash](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/forwards.htm) i.e. `(/)` along with the raw `(r)` switch or you have to use the escaped [backslash](https://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/location_of_backslash_key) i.e. `(\\)`.
  - So your effective line of code will be :

    ```
    chrome_driver_path = r'C:/Users/thangtruong/WebScraping/chromedriver.exe'
    service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    website = "https://www.amazon.com"
    driver.get(website)
    ```
- If your underlying [os](/questions/tagged/os) is [linux](/questions/tagged/linux):

  - You have to download **chromedriver_linux64** from the [ChromeDriver Download Location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) and untar it for usage.
  - Additionally, if you are explicitly specifying the *Chromedriver* binary path you **don't** have to provide any extension for the executable binary, effectively i.e. *chromedriver*.
  - While mentioning the *Chromedriver* binary path you have to use the single [forward slash](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/forwards.htm) i.e. `(/)`.
  - So your effective line of code will be :

    ```
    chrome_driver_path = '/Users/thangtruong/WebScraping/chromedriver'
    service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    website = "https://www.amazon.com")
    driver.get(website)
    ```
- If your underlying [os](/questions/tagged/os) is [macos](/questions/tagged/macos):

  - You have to download **chromedriver_mac64** from the [ChromeDriver Download Location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) and untar it for usage.
  - Additionally, if you are explicitly specifying the *Chromedriver* binary path you **don't** have to provide any extension for the executable binary, effectively i.e. *chromedriver*.
  - While mentioning the `chromedriver` binary path you have to use the single [forward slash](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/forwards.htm) i.e. `(/)`.
  - So your effective line of code will be :

    ```
    chrome_driver_path = '/Users/thangtruong/WebScraping/chromedriver'
    service = ChromeService(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    website = "https://www.amazon.com"
    driver.get(website)
    ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- ['Webdrivers' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo/47150939#47150939)

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem for me!!!